# Maintain complete cell range address when open several workbooks to loop through it

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I made a macro that creates different workbooks I'm trying to use it in a loop but the range changes to the open workbook and when I try to use the complete path to my workbook the variable in which I store the range marks "Nothing".

```
row = ActiveCell.row
Dim cell As Range
Dim quote As Integer

quotesToDo = Selection.Rows.Count


For quote = 1 To quotesToDo
    cell = Workbooks("PLANTILLA FORECAST 2019.xlsm").Worksheets("CONTROL DE LEADS").Range("D" & row)
    If cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        row = cell.row
        name = Range("D" & row).Value
        location = Range("G" & row).Value
        mail = Range("H" & row).Value
        phone = Range("I" & row).Value
        wantedProduct = Range("J" & row).Value
        Call Query2(exchange, name, location, mail, phone, generalAddress, row)
    End If
    row = row + 1
Next quote
```

Comment: I suggest you share some sample data and tell us exactly in what line is raising the error.

Comment: Thanks, the error yellows at cell = Workbooks[...] saying that there is nothing. What Query2 do is create 2 new workbooks. The Query2 macro works fine but the problem is that if I try to use "Selection" it changes to the active cell in the other workbooks and there is no the information that query2 function needs to function. For the previous reason I'm trying to store the range of the Selection but I think that I need to specify the workbook to which I'm refering, I just can't figure it out how to do it.

Comment: In order to provide you a specific answer, please share some sample data. Apart from the `Set` keyword that you're missing (see oliver's answer below) , you're going to run into problems because the way you are working with `Selection` and `ActiveCell`

Answer (score 0):

Please use `set` for `Range` object.